# Why is String.GetHashCode() implemented differently in 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the CLR?

Tags: c#, hash, clr

What are the technical reasons behind the difference between the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of string.GetHashCode()?

More importantly, why does the 64-bit version seem to terminate its algorithm when it encounters the NUL character? For example, the following expressions all return true when run under the 64-bit CLR.

```
"\0123456789".GetHashCode() == "\0987654321".GetHashCode()
"\0AAAAAAAAA".GetHashCode() == "\0BBBBBBBBB".GetHashCode()
"\0The".GetHashCode() == "\0Game".GetHashCode()
```

This behavior (bug?) manifested as a performance issue when we used such strings as keys in a Dictionary.

Comment: Very interesting find. In fact, it is most likely a bug - I can't imagine it is intended behavior, unless the hash function isn't meant for .Net strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a known issue which Microsoft would **not fix**:

> As you have mentioned this would be a breaking change for some programs (even though they shouldn't really be relying on this), the risk of this was deemed too high to fix this in the current release.
>
> I agree that the rate of collisions that this will cause in the default Dictionary<String, Object> will be inflated by this. If this is adversely effecting your applications performance, I would suggest trying to work around it by using one of the Dictionary constructors that takes an IEqualityComparer so you can provide a more appropriate GetHashCode implementation. I know this isn't ideal and would like to get this fixed in a future version of the .NET Framework.

Source: [Microsoft Connect - String.GetHashCode ignores any characters in the string beyond the first null byte in x64 runtime](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/519104/string-gethashcode-ignores-any-characters-in-the-string-beyond-the-first-null-byte-in-x64-runtime)

Comment: Too bad. This issue was certainly a puzzle. It took us a while to figure this out. Good thing we have the option of cleaning our strings before setting them as keys.

Comment: I don't understand any of this "breaking change" excuse. The comments in the source of GetHashCode show clearly that the calculation of the hash has never been considered permanent. Even if some fools have started to depend on it, they already have problems because the hashcode is architecture-dependent. It is a MS bug and it should be fixed. This has been slowing down my hash tables since 2010. And yes, I do need to convert my sometimes-'\0' bytes into strings, because strings are the fastest variable-size dictionary keys in .Net!

Answer (score 2):

Eric lippert has got a wondeful blog to this 
[Curious property in String](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/12/what-curious-property-does-this-string-have.aspx)

[Curious property Revealed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/15/the-curious-property-revealed.aspx)